# MATLAB how to obtain the eigenvalues from the PCA?

Tags: matlab

Does the PCA function gives you the eigenvalues or do I have to calculate them? If so, how? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the pca function you can use the return value latent to get the eigenvalues.

```
[coeff,score,latent] = pca(data)
```

see here http://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html?refresh=true#btjpztu-1

Alternatively you can compute the eigenvalues by yourself using the following code

```
[m, ~] = size(data);
Sigma = (1/m) * (data' * data);   
[~, S] = eig(Sigma);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've noticed that the PCA is performed with the covariance matrix, is there a way to do it using the correlation matrix instead?

Comment: This depends on your data and what you want to achieve. You might want to have a look at this post http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53/pca-on-correlation-or-covariance

Comment: In the code example you should first subtract the mean of the data before calculating the sigma.